# How to properly access bindingSource to SQL Server data?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, data-binding, dataset, bindingsource

I am new to vb and to SQL Server. I would like to know the exact procedure how to bind from start and only by code, `BindingSource` to SQL Server data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Dim connectionString = _conn_Test

dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand,           connectionString)

Dim commandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)

Dim table = New DataTable
table.Columns.Add("cie_code", GetType(System.String))
table.Columns.Add("cie_nom", GetType(System.String))

For i = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
    table.Rows.Add()
Next

dataAdapter.Fill(table)

bindingSource1.DataSource = table
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing up some Lines that not fit properly.

```
'Get data from a sqlserver and fill a datatable with those data
Dim connectionString = _conn_Test
Dim table = New DataTable
dataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(selectCommand,connectionString)
dataAdapter.Fill(table)
```

So now you have a table filled with all data from your Selectcommand query.

This table you can use as datasource for Listboxes datagridview or everything else with can have a datasource.
Another way tio create a datasource is

```
Dim bindingSource1 As BindingSource
bindingSource1.DataSource = table
```

This you can use also to populate Datagridviews or listboxes etc.

```
'Bild a new table as datasource
Dim table = New DataTable
'Add new Colmuns to the Table
table.Columns.Add("cie_code", GetType(System.String))
table.Columns.Add("cie_nom", GetType(System.String))
 'Add 1 new row can be encklosed in a for loop
  Dim newrow as As DataRo = table.NewRow()
  newrow ("cie_code") = "Youtext1"
  newrow ("cie_nom") = "Yourtext2"
  table.Rows.Add(newrow)
  'Change 1 Column of of all rows
  For i as Integer = 0 To table.Rows.Count - 1
    table.Rows(i).Item("cie_nom") = "newtext"
  Next
  'Define new elements to demonstrate what to do with datasouurces
  Dim ListBox1 As ListBox
  Dim bindingSource2 As BindingSource
  This would sow a Listbox with one element newtext
  bindingSource2.DataSource = table
  listBox1.DataSource = bindingSource2
  listBox1.DisplayMember = "cie_nom"
```

The last thing in the pot is

```
Dim commandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
```

You can change the data in your sql  server by doing the sql commands like in the link
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.insertcommand?view=netframework-4.8

Where you build you own update, insert and /or delete command to manipulate the data in the sql server.
Or you manipulate the data in your filled table, and let dot net do the work. By doing following line

```
Dim commandBuilder1 = New SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter)
'this next works with commandbuilder or your own sql ,commands
dataAdapter.Update(table)
```

For the future try to keep your question focussed on one problem.
When you want to do something enter in a search engine you plain text question with vb net at the start and see where it takes you. usually here or to microsoft docs and some other pages blogs etc there you might find inspiration to try it yourself.
The shown examples are often very easy, so that it can be explained properly. complex you have to figure out yourself or you are lucky and someone else has tried it and succeeded.
I hoped this helps a little